# Popup Jitter - Image pops down immediately after poping up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent a popup image from poping up and down repeatedly (forever) when the user moves the mouse to a location on the page.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/jitterbug-on-popup-25kp4 to illustrate the problem.   Hover over the text `Mouse over this and the Jitter Image will appear` to see the jitter problem.

EDIT: Since this was originally posted, I incorporated the solution into the code showing the problem, and now it also shows a solution.

## Details

What follows is a text description of the problem, but the code does illustrates the problem as well (and with a lot less text).

On a web page, that has a vertical scroll bar,

1. The user moves the mouse over a div which has a **MouseEnter** javascript handler.
2. the on **MouseEnter** event fires which causes an image to pop up.
3. The popup causes the scroll bar to scroll the content.  So now, the mouse is no longer hovering over the *hover item* so the **MouseLeave** event fires which causes the image to pop down.
4. With the image no longer being displayed, the scroll bar moves the content back to where it was prior to the popup and viola, the mouse is overtop of the div and the **MouseEnter** event fires again to pop up the image.

Steps 2-4 repeat forever at the speed at which the browser can keep up.
Or when the user moves the mouse to stop the popup/popdown from happening.

I've seen this happen on some other websites and now that it's happening to me, I want to fix it but I'm not sure how to.

I've searched for a solution but haven't found one yet.  Here are some links I found:

https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/ - This was good but suggests using min-height which doesn't work in my situation.

I've also tried using overflow: hidden which does prevent the jitter effect described above but leaves the user with no way to see the *rest of the popup image*.  This, however, is a better solution than the jitter effect described above.

I'm using AngularJS and JQuery if that affects the answer.

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve] here

Comment: I've added a link to an example that demonstrates the problem (and now the solution).  For the problem to occur in this example, I "force" it to occur.  In a more complex web page (that I was maintaining) it happened without me knowing what code was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position:absolute on the image, will solve this as it won't change the current flow when you display the image and the scroll bar will remain in it current position.